# How to Navigate between multiple browser windows using serinity

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, serenity-bdd

Serenity is a BDD based on selenium . I am using 3 window handlers . My requirement is something like this -

1. Open window 1
2. click an element on window 1 that will open window 2

3.click an element on window 2 that will open window 3

4. close all windows

All window handlers are getting inputs fine but still I am not able to switch between the windows

Answer (score 0):

This worked a bit fine for me in handling upto 2 windows but not for 3 -

```
public class MultipleWindowsHandle {


     WebDriver driver;  
     @Before  
     public void setup() throws Exception {  
     driver=new FirefoxDriver();  
     String URL="http://www.seleniummaster.com";   
     driver.get(URL);  
     driver.manage().window().maximize();  
     }  
     @Test  
     public void test() throws Exception {   
     // Opening site  
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='SeleniumMasterLogo']")).click();  
     // Storing parent window reference into a String Variable  
     String Parent_Window = driver.getWindowHandle();    
      // Switching from parent window to child window   
     for (String Child_Window : driver.getWindowHandles())  
     {  
     driver.switchTo().window(Child_Window);  
     // Performing actions on child window  
     driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown_txt")).click();  
     List  dropdownitems=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='DropDownitems']//div"));  
     int dropdownitems_Size=dropdownitems.size();  
     System.out.println("Dropdown item size is:"+dropdownitems_Size);  
     ((WebElement) dropdownitems.get(1)).click();  
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='anotherItemDiv']")).click();  
     }  
     //Switching back to Parent Window  
     driver.switchTo().window(Parent_Window);  
     //Performing some actions on Parent Window  
     driver.findElement(By.className("btn_style")).click();  
     }  
      @After  
      public void close() {  
      driver.quit();  
      }   
     }
```

Comment: Y u r using advanced forloop here

Comment: U can directly switch to the recent window by using this command. driver.getwindowHandle()

Answer (score 0):

```
//In first window - Do something to activate second window
//Actions ..... here

//Second window opens
//Following code handles second window
ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList (getDriver().getWindowHandles());
getDriver().switchTo().window(newTab.get(1));

//In second window - do some actions here
ArrayList<String> newTabs = new ArrayList<String> getDriver().getWindowHandles());
getDriver().switchTo().window((newTabs.get(2)));

//In Third Window        
//Do some actions here

//Close Third Window
getDriver().close(); //Disable if the action in third window closes third window like Cancel/OK button
//Switch back to second window
getDriver().switchTo().window(newTab.get(1));
//Close Second Window
getDriver().close();
//ghet back to initial (First) window
getDriver().switchTo().window(newTab.get(0));
```